# What is the difference, if any at all, between having a warrant for your arrest and being circulated as wanted in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, police, arrest, bail, warrant

What does it mean to have a warrant out for one's arrest?

How must a warrant be issued?

What institutions within society are able to issue a warrant?

What does it mean to be circulated to police bodies as 'wanted'?  Is it completely synonymous as having an open warrant for one's arrest?

What other types of compareable notices can be issued upon one's name and DoB across police systems?

What does missing bail reporting events result in?

How many types of bail are there in the UK?

Comment: Your questions about bail should really be a separate post.

Comment: What do you mean by "comparable notices"?

Comment: @Rick Fair point about bail. By comparable notices, I mean things that could lead to one being taken in upon encounters with authorities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

A warrant for arrest, also referred to as a bench warrant, is issued by a judge or magistrate to ensure a defendant (and sometimes a witness) appears before them.

"Being circulated" means a suspect is liable for arrest for an offence (without a warrant) and their details are put on [PNC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police_National_Computer) with sufficient information to justify being arrested if they come in to contact with the police - assuming PNC is checked that is.